# How can I hide AWS credentials from external program?

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

In my case I'm trying to hide the aws access keys and secret access keys that are printed through outputs.

I tried to implement a solution but unfortunately its printing the credentials in the plan. So whenever i push the code/commits to GITHUB we have terraform running in Jenkins it spits the plan in GITHUB exposing the credentials in terraform plan.

Although I have hidden in outputs but now I'm printing it in plan and exposing in GitHub. I also tried to use `sensitive:true` in outputs which will easily solve this problem. But my team wants to implement this solution :(

```
resource "aws_iam_access_key" "key" {
  user = "${aws_iam_user.user.name}"
}

resource "null_resource" "access_key_shell" {
  triggers = {
    aws_user = "${aws_iam_user.user.name}" // triggering an alert on the user, since if we pass aws_iam_access_key, access key is visible in plan.
  }
}

data "external" "stdout" {
  depends_on = ["null_resource.access_key_shell"]
  program    = ["sh", "${path.module}/read.sh"]

  query {
    access_id = "${aws_iam_access_key.key.id}"
    secret_id = "${aws_iam_access_key.key.secret}"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "contents_access" {
  triggers = {
    stdout = "${lookup(data.external.logstash_stdout.result, "access_key")}"
    value  = "${aws_iam_access_key.key.id}"
  }
}

output "aws_iam_podcast_logstash_access_key" {
  value = "${chomp(null_resource.contents_access.triggers["stdout"])}"
}
```

read.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eux
echo {\"access_key\":\"$(aws kms encrypt --key-id alias/amp_key --plaintext ${access_id}  --output text --query CiphertextBlob)\", > sample.json && echo \"secret_key\": \"$(aws kms encrypt --key-id alias/amp_key --plaintext ${secret_id} --output text --query CiphertextBlob)\"} >> sample.json
cat sample.json | jq -r '.access_key'
cat sample.json | jq -r '.secret_key'
```

My terraform plan :

```
<= data.external.stdout
      id:                <computed>
      program.#:         "2"
      program.0:         "sh"
      program.1:         "/Users/xxxx/projects/tf_iam_stage/read.sh"
      query.%:           "2"
      query.access_id:   "xxxxxxxx"  ----> I want to hide these values from the plan
      query.secret_id:   "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/x" ----> I want to hide these values from the plan
      result.%:          <computed>
```

Any help !
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would need to implement something that feeds directly into the `provider` for the credential arguments, such as Vault. There would be no opportunity for the credentials to display in that situation.

Comment: @MattSchuchard , Thats a very good solution ! But we don't want to set up vault only for this use case at present, is there any other way?

Comment: You could write your own provider for reading credentials locally.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things going on here.

First, you are leaking your credentials because you are storing your `.tfstate` in GitHub. This one has an easy solution. First, add `*.tfstate` to your `.gitignore`, then set a remote backend, and if you use S3, then checkout policies and ACLs to prevent public access.

Second, your other problem is that you are fetching the credentials on runtime, and during runtime Terraform displays everything unless you add the sensitive flag. So, basically if you want to follow this approach, you are forced to use `sensitive: true`, no matter what you team says. However, why get the credentials that way? Why don't you add a new provider with those credentials, set an alias for this provider, and just use it for the resources where you those keys?

Answer (score 0):

in your scenario you will be great if you will go with: `Remote State` approach.

`Remote State` allows Terraform to store the state in a remote store. Terraform supports storing state in places like Terraform Enterprise, Consul, S3, and more.

The setup is to create a bucket on AWS S3, it should not be readable or writeable by anyone, except the user who will be using for Terraform.

The code I added was;

```
 terraform {
    backend "s3" {
      bucket = "my-new-bucket"
      key = "state/key"
      region = "eu-west-1"
    }
  }
```

This simply tells Terraform to use S3 as the backend provider for doing things like storing `tfstate` files.

Don't forget to run `terraform init` because it's a requirement, Terraform will notice that you changed from storing locally to storing in S3.

Once that is done You could delete the local `tfstate` files safe in the knowledge your details were safely stored on S3.

Here is some useful docs: [Click docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html)

The second approach is to use a Terraform `plugin` more info here: [Terraform plugin](https://www.tweag.io/posts/2019-04-03-terraform-provider-secret.html)

Good luck!